# SQL Query that groups by sets that are unknown when the query is run

Tags: sql, sql-server, jasper-reports

I have been trying to develop a suitable query for building a stacked graph of admissions per admission source per year-month for a hospital.  To start I have a simple table that lists patient being admitted to a hospital by source and date:

```
vwAdmissons
--------------------
Source | VARCHAR(20)
Admit  | Date
--------------------
```

Some sample data

```
Accident and Emerg    17/12/13 03:18
Ward                  17/12/13 08:16
Accident and Emerg    17/12/13 15:52
OT/recovery           17/12/13 17:10
OT/recovery           17/12/13 22:22
OT/recovery           17/12/13 22:24
Accident and Emerg    17/12/13 23:49
Ward                  18/12/14 09:16
OT/recovery           18/12/14 11:40
OT/recovery           18/12/14 16:42
Ward                  18/12/14 17:48
OT/recovery           18/12/14 19:57
OT/recovery           18/12/14 19:58
Accident and Emerg    18/12/14 22:15
OT/recovery           19/12/14 00:00
OT/recovery           19/12/14 11:49
Ward                  19/12/14 12:11
OT/recovery           19/12/14 12:47
OT/recovery           19/12/14 16:43
OT/recovery           19/12/14 17:10
OT/recovery           19/12/14 17:45
Ward                  19/12/14 17:56
OT/recovery           20/12/14 00:10
Accident and Emerg    20/12/14 04:01
OT/recovery           20/12/14 05:46
Other Hospital        20/12/14 07:49
Ward                  20/12/14 18:43
```

I can run a SELECT on this table to Group Admission Sources by year-month and Source

```
SELECT Count(*)                                AS Total,
       dbo.vwAdmissons.Source,
       Year(dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit)             AS AdmitYear,
       Datename(month, dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit)  AS AdmitMonth,
       Datename(month, dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit) + ' '
       + RIGHT(Year(dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit), 2) AS Monthyear
FROM   dbo.vwAdmissons
GROUP  BY Year(dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit),
          Datename(month, dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit),
          dbo.vwAdmissons.Source
ORDER  BY Year(dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit),
          Datename(month, dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit),
          dbo.vwAdmissons.Source
```

This returns a list of year-month's and Source and count.

What I would really like is a List of year-month's which all source counts for a specific year-month within the same record.

```
year-month  source1 count, source2 count, source3 count
```

I am guessing that this is not possible for an unknown source list?

I am not sure what the alternative approaches are for building a stacked graph of source (percentages) for year-month?

The output I am really looking for is something like:

```
year-month  |  Accident and Emerg | Ward | OT/recovery
December-13        3                1      3
January-14
February-14
```

The issue really is that I would like the list of sources to be dynamic - I think somehow it really needs to be hard coded?

Any guidance appreciated

Comment: Your table has only one `source` column so from where you will get `source1,source2,etc..`

Comment: Source is a variable so at time 11:45 on 10th of December there was an admission from ED, at 12:00 on December 10th there was an admission from a Ward.  The sources can change over time - that is more sources can be added to the system

Comment: Okay, Whether source column has fixed set of values like Ed,Ward,etc..

Comment: not really - new values can be added although this is fairly rare

Comment: You need to use `Dynamic Pivot`. Can you add `sample data` and `expected output`.

Comment: I guess as an alternative being able to get a list of counts for known Sources against year-month's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NoDisplayName suggested, you'll need to delve into the dark arts of dynamic sql pivoting to do what you're trying to accomplish.

I have to do a query something like this a few times a year. Ultimately, it would be ideal to do this type of pivoting in a presentation-layer application like an Excel pivot table or an SSRS matrix, but if you need to do it in SQL, here's a way to do it.

Note that this is old school pivot syntax that I happen to prefer over the new t-sql PIVOT operator.

```
DECLARE @MyDynamicSQL varchar(2000)

/*@LINEBREAK is just something inserted at the end of lines to make the dynamic sql more readable if it needs to be debugged*/
DECLARE @LINEBREAK AS varchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 

/* Build the first line of the dynamic sql statement which is just a derived column we'll alias as "MonthYear" */
SET @MyDynamicSQL = 'SELECT [MonthYear] = Datename(month, dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit) + ''-'' + RIGHT(CAST(Year(dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit) AS varchar(4)),2) ' + @LINEBREAK

/* Append to the first line, the variable number of "Source" values that you'll want to pivot out as columns. Group By just gives the distinct list of Sources.
This syntax for building the string of columns is weird if you've never seen it before, but worth learning I think.
QUOTENAME simply ensures that the field names will be enclosed in brackets or quotes in the even that the returned values from this query contain spaces, etc.*/
SELECT @MyDynamicSQL = @MyDynamicSQL +
 ',' + QUOTENAME([Source]) + ' = COUNT(CASE [Source] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME([Source],'''') + ' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ' + @LINEBREAK
FROM dbo.vwAdmissons
GROUP BY [Source]

/*Rest of the dynamic SQL - same as what you had but notice there's source column in the group by*/
SET @MyDynamicSQL = @MyDynamicSQL + 'FROM   dbo.vwAdmissons
GROUP  BY Year(dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit),
          Datename(month, dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit)
ORDER  BY Year(dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit),
          Datename(month, dbo.vwAdmissons.Admit)'

PRINT (@MyDynamicSQL) --this is just for debugging/testing
EXEC(@MyDynamicSQL)
```